# Unable to open camera in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the following code to open camera or gallery from my iPad app. which supports only landscape orientation.

i have implemented the below code :

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate=self;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
#else
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    picker.showsCameraControls=YES;
   [picker setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff];
#endif
CGAffineTransform transform=picker.view.transform;
transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90*M_PI/180);
[picker setCameraViewTransform:transform];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Please help.

Comment: Why are you apply transform for your picker view? Is your app supported landscape mode?

Comment: My app supports only landscape mode and after doing a lot of R n D i came to know that iPad dose not open camera or gallery in landscape mode so i was forcing to open in portrait mode.

Comment: have you been able to open it in landscape mode..